# Does Jasmine 2.0 really not work with require.js?

Tags: requirejs, jasmine

I'm setting up my SpecRunner.html/.js, RequireConfig.js, my paths and my shims just like I have with earlier release candidates of Jasmine + RequireJs, but now my test methods show Jasmine undefined. They've recently changed to a different method of loading Jasmine that I understand is incompatible with RequireJs.

Is my understanding correct? If so, will we ever be able to use Jasmine + RequireJs again?

Answer (score 70):

The new boot.js does a bunch of the initialization and attaches it to window.onload() which has already been called by the time require.js loads Jasmine. You can manually call window.onload() to initialize the HTML Reporter and execute the environment.

SpecRunner.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

    <!-- specRunner.js runs all of the tests -->
    <script data-main="specRunner" src="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

specRunner.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // Configure RequireJS to shim Jasmine
  require.config({
    baseUrl: '..',
    paths: {
      'jasmine': 'tests/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine',
      'jasmine-html': 'tests/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html',
      'boot': 'tests/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot'
    },
    shim: {
      'jasmine': {
        exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
      },
      'jasmine-html': {
        deps: ['jasmine'],
        exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
      },
      'boot': {
        deps: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-html'],
        exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
      }
    }
  });

  // Define all of your specs here. These are RequireJS modules.
  var specs = [
    'tests/spec/routerSpec'
  ];

  // Load Jasmine - This will still create all of the normal Jasmine browser globals unless `boot.js` is re-written to use the
  // AMD or UMD specs. `boot.js` will do a bunch of configuration and attach it's initializers to `window.onload()`. Because
  // we are using RequireJS `window.onload()` has already been triggered so we have to manually call it again. This will
  // initialize the HTML Reporter and execute the environment.
  require(['boot'], function () {

    // Load the specs
    require(specs, function () {

      // Initialize the HTML Reporter and execute the environment (setup by `boot.js`)
      window.onload();
    });
  });
})();
```

Example spec

```
define(['router'], function(router) {
  'use strict';

  describe('router', function() {
    it('should have routes defined', function() {
      router.config({});
      expect(router.routes).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I've spent an afternoon trying to get this working.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this and it works great! I even appended it to a view by altering the `boot.js` file and having it load in the div of my choosing.

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot! I fiddled around forever and this got me started instantly.

Comment: This answer helped a lot, but calling window.onload() caused other code to be rerun too. Ended up with a custom boot.js which removed the window.onload() and placed it in a function. Refer https://github.com/erikringsmuth/jasmine2-amd-specrunner/

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 13):

Here's an alternative approach that may be simpler in some cases - use [Jasmine's asynchronous support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) to load your AMD module before executing tests, like this:

in **MySpec.js**:

```
describe('A suite', function() {
  var myModule;

  // Use require.js to fetch the module
  it("should load the AMD module", function(done) {
    require(['myModule'], function (loadedModule) {
      myModule = loadedModule;
      done();
    });
  });

  //run tests that use the myModule object
  it("can access the AMD module", function() {
    expect(myModule.speak()).toBe("hello");
  });
});
```

For this to work, you'll need to include require.js in your SpecRunner.html and possibly [configure require](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) (as you normally would, e.g. by setting the baseUrl), like this:

in **SpecRunner.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

    <script src="lib/require.min.js"></script>
    <script> require.config({ baseUrl: "src" }); </script>

    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

    <script src="spec/MySpec.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

For this example, the AMD module implementation might look something like this:

in **src/myModule.js**:

```
define([], function () {
  return {
    speak: function () {
      return "hello";
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a [working Plunk that implements this complete example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PK0t7rMIntlMvqk2spre?p=preview).

Enjoy!

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use done() in the beforeEach() function so that it will run before each spec. Then you can run each spec separately without requiring the module loading spec to be run.