# Jasmine 2.0 TeamCity reporter

Tags: javascript, teamcity, jasmine, phantomjs

Had a working CI build with teamcity, requirejs, and jasmine 1.3 running phantomjs.exe and I'm trying to upgrade jasmine to version 2.0.

I got a basic html specrunner page working following this great post. (jasmine is now loaded on windows.onload, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20851265/564577)

Now I'm trying to get the teamcity-reporter working. (from the plugins page under testing framework, http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+Plugins#)

It has a dependency on the jasmine global and doesn't see it, even though I can console.log the jasmine.version, but really my question is does anybody have one that works, or has a good explanation on how the reporters are loaded and how they work now in jasmine 2.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a day of poking around it was easy to write.

I'll keep the most updated script in https://github.com/WilliamDoman/Jasmine2.0TeamCityReporter

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out how to install your plugin. Is it just the js file in the repo that I need or is there another plugin that references?

Comment: it works with Jasmine 2.0+ which is a javascript unit test framework.  If you get that working, you then you can use my TeamcityReporter with Teamcity to report the results.  There isnt really an install other than Team City.  You would have to include the js file though

Comment: A nice guy named Scott had a pull request with more detailed instructions so I merged them in.  They look about right, I didn't verify every step, but they look very good.

Comment: This blog post shows how to set it up https://dev.to/seankilleen/how-to-show-jasmine-test-results-in-teamcity-1l3p